# Linux: How to read-enable dynamic mice

Tags: linux, drivers, mouse, udev

I have an app that reads input from 4 (four) mice that are plugged in via USB in addition to the built-in touchpad. This is no problem for Ubuntu 9.10: hald notices the new devices and udev's them brand new entries called `/dev/input/mouse4` ... `mouse7`.

My app runs as a normal user app. The files in `/dev` belong to `root` and aren't readable to anyone else.

I don't have a problem doing `chmod a+r mouse?` once, but the devices come and go with every reboot and every time the dang rodents are plugged in or out.

Can someone please tell me a script or something to manipulate so my `chmod` happens automagically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read up on [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html).  I've never dealt with that stuff myself, so I couldn't give you an outright solution right now, but I'm certain it's in that document.  Sorry about the RTFM solution.  Hopefully someone else has more experience with that stuff than I.

Comment: Hey, that's fine! Thanks for the pointer, I think I'll be fine from here on.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same problem, here's what I discovered:

Being a debian, Ubuntu keeps most of its rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d`. The directory `/etc/udev/rules.d` is only for manually introduced exceptions; they will apparently override the settings in `/lib/udev/rules.d`.

Mice are among the basic stuff handled by udev, I wasn't surprised to find a handful of settings for them in `lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules`. The paragraph of interest to me was:

```
# input
KERNEL=="mouse*|mice|event*",   MODE="0640"
KERNEL=="ts[0-9]*|uinput",      MODE="0640"
KERNEL=="js[0-9]*",             MODE="0644"
```

I willfully ignored the warning at the top of the file:

```
# do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update
```

as I intend for this change to be temporary anyway.

I changed the first "640" to "644", unplugged and re-plugged two of my mice. And presto,

```
crw-r----- 1 root root 13, 32 2009-11-16 19:14 mouse0
crw-r----- 1 root root 13, 33 2009-11-16 19:14 mouse1
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 13, 34 2009-11-16 21:58 mouse2
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 13, 35 2009-11-16 21:58 mouse3
```

`mouse2` and `mouse3` became world-readable. Mission accomplished!